# Is the following question correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure if the following question is correct in formal English: "Why not do it?" Would it be better to say "Why don't you do it", but then the question is related to the sentence "if you can afford it".
Thank you!

Comment: "Why not do it?" is quite abrupt and suggests an element of criticism, whereas a more polite version such as "why don't you do it?" has a more conciliatory tone and would be viewed as more polite, certainly in the UK and Ireland...it may be that it is different in other jurisdictions.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now that you mention it, I might have used it before between friends, as an encouraging question... Thank you.